# Graphql Error while posting contact Information

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql

I have an angular form where I am trying to post(muatation) customer contact info using graphQL.
However when I click on submit button I get this error.
I tried googling but I coudn't find relevant help.
Does someone know how to resolve this error or can explain me what to do.

```
Error: GraphQL error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2019-04-28T18:30:00.000Z": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

[image]

Initially I am trying to push the contact Info in an array which looks like this:

```
{agreementId: "123", contactType: "phone", contactDescription: "", 
contactSubType: "mobile", contactSubTypeDescription: "", …}
agreementId: "123"
contactDescription: ""
contactSubType: "mobile"
contactSubTypeDescription: ""
contactType: "phone"
endDate: Sun Apr 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
lastVerifiedDate: Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
referenceNumber: "123"
startDate: Fri Apr 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
```

I am getting Date from Mat-Date picker using ngModel.
However now when I try to post this Info to graphQl it throws the following error:

```
ERROR:
there was an error sending the query Error: GraphQL error: Cannot 
deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2019-04- 
27T18:30:00.000Z": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: 
com.statefarm.mdm.model.customer.Customer["contact"]- 
>java.util.ArrayList[0]- 
>com.statefarm.mdm.model.customer.Contact["endDate"])
at new ApolloError (bundle.esm.js:60)
at QueryManager.<anonymous> (bundle.esm.js:980)
at step (tslib.es6.js:97)
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:78)
at tslib.es6.js:71
at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:891)
at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:67)
at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:972)
at notifySubscription (Observable.js:130)
at onNotify (Observable.js:165)
```

Comment: @DanielRearden Can you please explain what can be the issue from server side? I can't even understand what the error is trying to say

Comment: Might not be a dupe, actually. From the error message, it sounds like there's a mismatch between the format expected for a Date scalar and what's actually being provided. Are you sending a date as an input? If so, can you update your question with the query you're actually sending, and the variables that are being sent along with it?

Comment: Also, when posting code, error messages, etc. please paste the actual text if possible rather than providing a screenshot. This makes the content of your post searchable and means even if your screenshot is taken down, your post will continue to be readable.

Comment: @DanielRearden I have updated my Question. Moreover, in the server side, there is a millisecond timestamp but that cannot be removed so I have to handle it at my side